# Model not updated in google maps listener - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have a function, `$scope.addReport()`, that is supposed to do the following:

- add event listener on click to add a new marker (by executing placeMarker(location))
- update the `$scope.TempMarker` model with the new coordinates
- show the form which has `ng-show="showForm'` directive
- remove the listener so only one marker can be placed

Trouble that I am having is that if I try to change `$scope.showForm` within the listener, it doesn't update the scope, it evaluates as true only within the listener. If I move it out of the listener, the scope is updated and the form is shown.

So my question is why scope is not updating for `$scope.showForm` but it is updating for `$scope.TempMarker`, and how can I update it within the listener?

Here is the code:

```
//attached to ng-show directive 
$scope.showForm = false;

//this function creates a marker based on passed location
function placeMarker(location) {
      $scope.tempMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location, 
          map: $scope.map,
          draggable: true
      });
  }

//this is executed on addReport() click
$scope.addReport = function() {
  //$scope.showForm = !$scope.showForm; ---> if declaration is here, scope is updated and the form is shown
  var newMarkerListener = google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'click', function(event) {
      placeMarker(event.latLng); // create the actual marker

      //update the new report object
      $scope.newReport.lat = event.latLng.lat();
      $scope.newReport.lng = event.latLng.lng();
      $scope.showForm = !$scope.showForm; // -----> not updating the scope
      console.log($scope.showForm) // logs true
      google.maps.event.addListener($scope.tempMarker,'dragend',function(event) {
          $scope.newReport.lat = event.latLng.lat();
          $scope.newReport.lng = event.latLng.lng();
      });

     google.maps.event.removeListener(newMarkerListener);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try wrap it with $apply

```
$scope.$apply(function () { 
   $scope.showForm = !$scope.showForm; 
});
```

Extension:

Angular uses apply on several async cases:

1. Events (ng-click etc)
2. Ajax calls
3. Timeouts

When using a non-trivial async operation, the bind will not occure automatically after the assignment so it's better to use $apply.

[Extend with a great article](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Comment: @BojanaŠekeljić great! I extended my answer